# POST Call inside Bootstrap Model

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have been playing around with my codes and can't seem to make it work in a modal but working fine in a regular php file. The code is suppose to check the availability of the username and display comment in a div.

This is the code working fine in a regular php file.. (no modal and no link of bootstrap)

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" ></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#feedback').load('chk.php').show();
               
               $('#username_input').keyup(function(){
                  $.post('chk.php', { username: regForm.username.value }, 
                  function(result) {
                      $('#feedback').html(result).show();
                  });
               });
            });
        </script>
  <form name="regForm">
      
      username : <br/>
      <input type="text" id="username_input" name="username" >
  </form>
  <div id="feedback">
      Im here
  </div>
```

and below is another php file that is responsible to receive the value from the form and make a query in the database

```
require '../scripts/connection.php';

$username = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'));


$loggeduserName ="";
$tb_line =0;

$res = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :searcname');
$res ->execute(array('searcname' => $username));
echo '<br />';
  $data_exists = ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;
echo $username , '<br/>';
if ($username == null){
    echo 'Choose a username';
} else if (strlen($username) < 6) {
    echo 'Too Short';
} else if (strlen($username) > 12 ) {
    echo 'username must not exceed 12 char long';
} else if ($data_exists > 0){
    echo "username ", $username , " is already <font color='red'>taken</font>" ;
} else {
    echo "username ", $username , " is already <font color='blue'>available</font>" ;
}
```

they are working fine and I need help how to implement it inside a modal. I cant seem to make it work and seems that line below is not firing

```html
$('#feedback').load('chk.php').show();
```

by the way I am using bootstrap in index.php where the modal is called..

Will appreciate any suggestion on how to solve this issue.. Thanks in advance

Comment: is modal opening or not. where is your modal code to make #feedback as modal ?

Comment: @Venkatraman the modal opens when the trigger is clicked "register" the modal is placed in the header.php the javascript is also there and working properly in other functions like counting keypressed.. (I used that just to check if javascript is working..)

Comment: your modal only says its taken or available not the whole form inside modal. is that correct ?

Comment: the form is inside the modal. and inside the form there is a small div where the comment will be displayed.

Comment: Since you are trying in ajax. it will response html output not html code. i dont see any real use of doing $('#feedback').load('chk.php').show();

Comment: I beleive that $('#feedback').load('chk.php').show(); dynamically show comment if username typed is already taken or too short or too long and that is being displayed in a div with an id of feedback

I am not expecting an html code as an output..